# Adding numbers using Java Long wrapper versus primitive longs

Tags: java, performance, object, profiling, primitive

I am running this code and getting unexpected results. I expect that the loop which adds the primitives would perform much faster, but the results do not agree.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long limit = 1000000000; //10^9
        long value = 0;
        for(long i = 0; i < limit; ++i){}
        long i;
        output.append("Base time\n");
        output.append(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms\n");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
            value = value + j;
        }
        output.append("Using longs\n");
        output.append(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms\n");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        value = 0;
        for(long k = 0; k < limit; ++k) {
            value = value + (new Long(k));
        }
        output.append("Using Longs\n");
        output.append(System.currentTimeMillis() - start + "ms\n");
        System.out.print(output);
    }
}
```

Output:

**Base time
359ms
Using longs
1842ms
Using Longs
614ms**

I have tried running each individual test in it's own java program, but the results are the same. What could cause this?

Small detail: running java 1.6

Edit:
I asked 2 other people to try out this code, one gets the same exact strange results that I get. The other gets results that actually make sense! I asked the guy who got normal results to give us his class binary. We run it and we STILL get the strange results. The problem is not at compile time (I think). I'm running 1.6.0_31, the guy who gets normal results is on 1.6.0_16, the guy who gets strange results like I do is on 1.7.0_04.

Edit: Get same results with a Thread.sleep(5000) at the start of program. Also get the same results with a while loop around the whole program (to see if the times would converge to normal times after java was fully started up)

Comment: It could be anything from lack of warm-up, that the operation is optimized away value isn't used etc. There is a significant penalty to autoboxing and if you instead used a Long as a counter in the loop you would see it for sure.

Comment: Another think to take into account is the rest of the code. It could be that the StringBuilder hits a resize limit in the first case. Because you don't take a start and a stop timestamp but just the start  and then the stop timestamp as part of the output building you will not know.

Comment: Good way to improve this test Fredrik, but not sure if it could cause 1 second of difference!

Comment: Make sure you do proper warm-up, fix the code I'd  be surprised if you would see the same thing. Have you checked what happens if you do it in the opposite order?

Comment: I have tried doing it in the opposite order, same results.  How do I ensure I get a proper warm-up?

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar - my answer answers that.

Comment: @Rodrigo Salazar - please run my test (feel free to increase "limit" and/or "ntimes" as needed, please run Steven C's test, and please post the *complete* results.  Thank you in advance .. PSM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this is a JVM warmup effect.  Specifically, the code is being JIT compiled at some point, and this is distorting the times that you are seeing.

Put the whole lot in a loop, and ignore the times reported until they stabilize.  (But note that they won't entirely stabilize.  Garbage is being generated, and therefore the GC will need to kick occasionally.  This is liable to distort the timings, at least a bit.  The best way to deal with this is to run a huge number of iterations of the outer loop, and calculate / display the average times.)

Another problem is that the JIT compiler on some releases of Java *may* be able to optimize away the stuff you are trying to test:

- It could figure out that the creation and immediate unboxing of the `Long` objects could be optimized away.  (Thanks Louis!)
- It could figure out that the loops are doing "busy work" ... and optimize them away entirely.   (The value of `value` is not used once each loop ends.)

---

FWIW, it is generally recommended that you use `Long.valueOf(long)` rather than `new Long(long)` because the former can make use of a cached `Long` instance.  However, in this case, we can predict that there will be a cache miss in all but the first few loop iterations, so the recommendation is not going to help.  If anything, it is likely to make the loop in question slower.

---

**UPDATE**

I did some investigation of my own, and ended up with the following:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
        test();
        }
    }

    private static void test() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long limit = 10000000; //10^9
        long value = 0;
        for(long i = 0; i < limit; ++i){}
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long j = 0; j < limit; ++j) {
            value = value + j;
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(long k = 0; k < limit; ++k) {
            value = value + (new Long(k));
        }
        long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        System.out.print(t1 + " " + t2 + " " + t3 + " " + value + "\n");
    }
}
```

which gave me the following output.

```
28 58 2220 99999990000000
40 58 2182 99999990000000
36 49 157 99999990000000
34 51 157 99999990000000
37 49 158 99999990000000
33 52 158 99999990000000
33 50 159 99999990000000
33 54 159 99999990000000
35 52 159 99999990000000
33 52 159 99999990000000
31 50 157 99999990000000
34 51 156 99999990000000
33 50 159 99999990000000
```

Note that the first two columns are pretty stable, but the third one shows a significant speedup on the 3rd iteration ... probably indicating that JIT compilation has occurred.

Interestingly, before I separated out the test into a separate method, I didn't see the speedup on the 3rd iteration. The numbers all looked like the first two rows.  And that seems to be  saying that the JVM (that I'm using) won't JIT compile a method that is currently executing ... or something like that.

Anyway, this demonstrates (to me) that there should be a warm up effect.  If you don't see a warmup effect, your benchmark is doing something that is inhibiting JIT compilation ... and therefore isn't meaningful for real applications.

Comment: I can't help but wonder if the JIT might be getting smart enough to e.g. elide some of the autoboxing.  (Certainly, if I were writing a JIT, that'd be a thing on my mind...)

Comment: I agree.  That is certainly a possibility to consider ... in interpretting the results that he gets after fixing the warmup flaw.  But right now, the numbers are simply unreliable.

Comment: I tried fixing the warm-up problem by placing a 5 second Thread.sleep at the start of the program. I get identical results. Is this a proper way to get around the possible warm-up issue?

Comment: @RodrigoSalazar - please **read** the second paragraph of my answer.  It tells you how to deal with warmup effects, etcetera.

Comment: Oh I just understood what you meant. Will try it!

Comment: Just tried it, I get the ~same thing printed out for every iteration of the while loop. Many many times. I guess it's not warm up time.

Comment: I also made sure to print out the 'value' variable to ensure that it is used and not optimized out!

Comment: @StephenC The reason you get different results when separating it out to a separate method is probably that the hotspot decide what to compile based on the number of times you have entered a method. If you have it all in main, you're likely to just hit main() once.

Comment: @Fredrik - I know that.  That's why I did it.

Comment: I **suspected** that JVM warmup (in general) is this was *his* problem ... before he showed us the code.  I **knew** that if I separated the test part out into a separate method, I could be sure that the method was JIT compiled ... and that is why I did that in my version of the benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised, too.

My first guess would have been inadvertant "[autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)", but that's clearly not an issue in your example code.

This link might give a clue:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html
>
> valueOf
>
> public static Long valueOf(long l)
>
> Returns a Long instance representing the specified long value. If a new Long instance is not required, this method should generally be
>   used in preference to the constructor Long(long), as this method is
>   likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by
>   caching frequently requested values.
>
> ```
> Parameters:
>     l - a long value. 
>
> Returns:
>     a Long instance representing l.
>
> Since:
>     1.5
> ```

But yes, I would expect using a wrapper (e.g. "Long") to take MORE time, and MORE space.  I would *not* expect using the wrapper to be three times *FASTER*!

================================================================================

ADDENDUM:

I got these results with your code:

```
Base time     6878ms
Using longs  10515ms
Using Longs 428022ms
```

I'm running JDK 1.6.0_16 on a pokey 32-bit, single-core CPU.

Comment: Yea, you seem to be getting expected results. I found someone that also gets expected results. Having them send me their binary and running it, I still get the same results I was getting before. I.e. I'm convinced certain environments get some strange effects, maybe only during java start-up, I am not sure.

Comment: Easy enough to verify:  1) run the tests a couple of times in the same program.  ALSO: 2) don't print the results until the end (separate out possible I/O side effects).  Let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

OK - here's a slightly different version, along with my results (running JDK 1.6.0_16 pokey 32-bit single-code CPU):

```
import java.util.*;

/*
Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf
----      ----   -----  ---------  -------------
   0       343     896       3431           6025
   1       342     957       3401           5796
   2       342     881       3379           5742
*/

public class LongTest {

    private static int limit = 100000000;
    private static int ntimes = 3;
    private static final long[] base = new long[ntimes];
    private static final long[] primitives = new long[ntimes];
    private static final long[] wrappers1 = new long[ntimes];
    private static final long[] wrappers2 = new long[ntimes];

    private static void test_base (int idx) {
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i){}
       base[idx] = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }

    private static void test_primitive (int idx) {
       long value = 0;
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i){
         value = value + i;
       }
       primitives[idx] = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }

    private static void test_wrappers1 (int idx) {
       long value = 0;
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i){
         value = value + new Long(i);
       }
       wrappers1[idx] = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }

    private static void test_wrappers2 (int idx) {
       long value = 0;
       long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
       for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i){
         value = value + Long.valueOf(i);
       }
       wrappers2[idx] = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      for (int i=0; i < ntimes; i++) {
         test_base (i);
            test_primitive(i);
            test_wrappers1 (i);
            test_wrappers2 (i);
      }

      System.out.println ("Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf");
      System.out.println ("----      ----   -----  ---------  -------------");
      for (int i=0; i < ntimes; i++) {
         System.out.printf ("  %2d    %6d  %6d     %6d         %6d\n",
            i, base[i], primitives[i], wrappers1[i], wrappers2[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

=======================================================================

5.28.2012:

Here are some additional timings, from a faster (but still modest), dual-core CPU running Windows 7/64 and running the same JDK revision 1.6.0_16:

```
/*
PC 1: limit = 100,000,000, ntimes = 3, JDK 1.6.0_16 (32-bit):
Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf
----      ----   -----  ---------  -------------
   0       343     896       3431           6025
   1       342     957       3401           5796
   2       342     881       3379           5742

PC 2: limit = 1,000,000,000, ntimes = 5,JDK 1.6.0_16 (64-bit):
Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf
----      ----   -----  ---------  -------------
   0         3       2       5627           5573
   1         0       0       5494           5537
   2         0       0       5475           5530
   3         0       0       5477           5505
   4         0       0       5487           5508

PC 2: "for loop" counters => long; limit = 10,000,000,000, ntimes = 5:
Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf
----      ----   -----  ---------  -------------
   0      6278    6302      53713          54064
   1      6273    6286      53547          53999
   2      6273    6294      53606          53986
   3      6274    6325      53593          53938
   4      6274    6279      53566          53974
*/
```

You'll notice:

1. I'm not using StringBuilder, and I separate out all of the I/O until the end of the program.
2. "long" primtive is consistently equivalent to a "no-op"
3. "Long" wrappers are consistently much, much slower
4. "new Long()" is slightly faster than "Long.valueOf()"
5. Changing the loop counters from "int" to "long" makes the first two columns ("base" and "longs" *much* slower.
6. "JIT warmup" is negligible after the the first few iterations...
7. ... *provided* I/O (like System.out) and potentially memory-intensive activities (like StringBuilder) are moved *outside* of the actual test sections.

Comment: My output with core i7, java 1.6.0_34
Test      Base   longs  Longs/new  Longs/valueOf
   2         0       0       1260           1275

Comment: @Rodrigo Salazar - Please list *all* of the rows, not just the top one.  Please increase "limit" so that all the timings are > 0 on your PC.